# Error when sending data from an Angular component to dialog

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

In my Angular code, I am required to send some data from a component to the dialog component. I have beginner programming skills so please bear with me.

The data is in the form of json file as:

```
[
{"data": [40, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], "label": "Score", "a":1, "score": 5, "improvement": "+1"}
]
```

Here is how I am doing it

```
import { DialogFBComponent } from '../dialog-fb/dialog-fb.component';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import histGData2 from '../../assets/data/histGraphDialog.json';
export interface graphInt {
    data: number;
    label: string;
    a: number;
  }
export class StartWorkoutComponent implements OnInit{
    public  dialogRef:any;
    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog){}
    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogFBComponent, histGData2 );
    }
}
```

and in the dialog component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dialog-fb',
    templateUrl: './dialog-fb.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dialog-fb.component.css']
})
export class DialogFBComponent
{
    graphData: graphInt[];
    constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public histGData2:any){}
     public lineChartOptions = 
     {
         scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
         responsive: true,
         fill: false
     };

    public lineChartLabels = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'];
    public lineChartColors = [
    { // grey
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
        pointBorderColor: '#fff',
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
        pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
    }];
    public lineChartType = 'line';
    public lineChartLegend = true;  public lineChartData = this.histGData2;
    score=this.histGData2[0].score;
    imp = this.histGData2[0].improvement;
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at new DialogFBComponent (dialog-fb.component.ts:43)
    at createClass (core.js:20716)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:20595)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:21821)
    at createRootView (core.js:21735)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:22767)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:22253)
    at ComponentFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:20074)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.js:9717)
    at ViewContainerRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewContainerRef_.createComponent (core.js:20185)
```

Comment: Put `if` check point for data existence `his.histGData2.length`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use instance of dialogRef for passing the data and then you won't need to send the data in the constructor.

```
 this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogFBComponent, {
      height: 'auto',
      disableClose: true,
      autoFocus: false,
    });
    let instance = this.dialogRef.componentInstance;
     instance.histGData2 = histGData2
```

And update your dialog component as below:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dialog-fb',
    templateUrl: './dialog-fb.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dialog-fb.component.css']
})
export class DialogFBComponent
{
    graphData: graphInt[];
     histGData2:any;
    
     public lineChartOptions = 
     {
         scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
         responsive: true,
         fill: false
     };

    public lineChartLabels = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'];
    public lineChartColors = [
    { // grey
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
        pointBorderColor: '#fff',
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
        pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
    }];
    public lineChartType = 'line';
    public lineChartLegend = true;  
    public lineChartData:any;
    score:any;
    imp:any;
    constructor(){
   if(this.histGData2 && this.histGData2.length){
    this.lineChartData = this.histGData2;
    this.score=this.histGData2[0].score;
    this.imp = this.histGData2[0].improvement;}
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right. Addition for extra check for length is always good. Upvoted your answer @MinalShah

Comment: This seems to take the code a step further, but now I am getting this error ERROR Error: ng-charts configuration error, data or datasets field are required to render chart line at BaseChartDirective.push../node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm5/ng2-charts.js.BaseChartDirective.getDatasets (ng2-charts.js:940) ...

Comment: This error is not related to the problem you have mentioned so far. Here we are just setting the configurations. You have to use them properly while rendering the chart. The error is during the chart render.

Comment: @Minal Shah I have tried directly importing the data in the fb-component and it renders perfectly

Comment: Yeah even that you can do. That is just the other way of doing. But the above code should also work.

Comment: To further check, I have used console.log(this.histGData2); at the end of the constructor and the value printed is 'undefined'

Comment: I guess it's because the fb-component is called before passing the value of hisGData2, can we dynamically call it?

Answer (score 0):

Set default values :

```
score = 0;
imp = '';
if(this.histGData2.length > 0 ){ 
   score=this.histGData2[0].score;
   imp = this.histGData2[0].improvement;
}
```

This error coming because you are access 0th element which doesn't exist. `null` variable.

Comment: I presume you typed this twice by mistake. Could you clarify why this is null. I cannot use default values as those would mean nothing in the application

Comment: but if you don't have data you have handle this case also otherwise it will throw error whenever data is blank. This is one level of error handling.

Comment: You are right about that, what I do not understand is that why the value is null. I checked by printing it before sending and it shows the values.

Comment: Then you refer @MinalShah answer. Mentioned about assigned reference variable.  What you printing try to print same variable in same component. if you are able to get no issue. but always good to handle this. You might be getting variable in other component.